# Hibernate: collection performance: many-to-many association with a set

Tags: hibernate, orm

From the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-collections-mostefficientupdate):

> There is, arguably, one more advantage that indexed collections have
>   over sets for many-to-many associations or collections of values.
>   Because of the structure of a Set, Hibernate does not UPDATE a row
>   when an element is "changed". Changes to a Set always work via INSERT
>   and DELETE of individual rows. Once again, this consideration does not
>   apply to one-to-many associations.

I am wondering:

1. How can there be a many-to-many collection of values (i.e. value types)...? I thought value types have only one owner...?
2. Why, in the case of a many-to-many association with a set, Hibernate does not UPDATE when an element in the set is changed, and instead uses INSERT and DELETE?